# intermittent Button.INVISIBLE results in android

Tags: android, button, asynchronous, visible

Within my UI thread I have the following code which works perfectly

```
public void showButtons(boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        mTextView.setText(currentSwipe.cardID);
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        mTextView.setText(R.string.Please_swipe);
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I also have this Async class

```
private class AwaitResponse extends  AsyncTask<clockItem, Void, Boolean>{
    protected Boolean doInBackground(clockItem... params){
        clockItem rSwipe = (clockItem)params[0];
        Calendar cSwipe = rSwipe.swipeDate;
        SystemClock.sleep(5000);
        if (currentSwipe.swipeDate == cSwipe)
        {
            currentSwipeSave();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean SwipeActive){
        if (SwipeActive) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
            mTextView.setText(R.string.Please_swipe);
        }
    }
}
```

Within the onPostExecute I have tried calling the showButtons(false) which has the same result as this code that is to change the text on mTextView but leave the Buttons visible.  They seem to be disabled but remain visible.  If I remark out the setText line, the Buttons react correctly i.e. disappear.

Am I missing something obvious here?

The idea is once an nfc swipe is read, the user is presented with 2 buttons.  If neither button is pressed after 5 seconds, an indeterminate direction is filed against the swipe.  If a button is pressed, the appropriate direction is filed and the screen resets (hide buttons and show default text) ready for the next swipe.  If a swipe is recorded, no buttons are pressed and a new swipe is made within 5 seconds, the previous swipe is files with an indeterminate direction and the new swipe options are displayed.

All of this seems to be working apart from the reset of the screen after the 5 second timeout.  Any ideas why this may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
public void showButtons(boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        mTextView.setText(currentSwipe.cardID);
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        mTextView.setText(R.string.Please_swipe);
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

private class AwaitResponse extends  AsyncTask<clockItem, Void, Boolean>{
    protected Boolean doInBackground(clockItem... params){
        clockItem rSwipe = (clockItem)params[0];
        Calendar cSwipe = rSwipe.swipeDate;
        SystemClock.sleep(5000);
        if (currentSwipe.swipeDate == cSwipe)
        {
            currentSwipeSave();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean SwipeActive){
        if (SwipeActive) {
            showButtons(!SwipeActive);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does seem that people prefer View.INVISIBLE over Button.INVISIBLE.  I've no idea if the values behind them are any different or not.  I like the !SwipeActive, that's neater.  However, both of the suggestions seem to result in the same issues.

The main thing I have an issue with is, going back to the original version, the removal up the setText line means that the buttons do disappear correctly when I run this code.  However, with the setText line, only the text is updated and the buttons remain on the screen!

Comment: then try by adding the `super.onPostExecute(SwipeActive);` before the if statement inside the `onPostExecute`

Comment: No change to the result.  Tried with both the method call as well as the explicit code within the if statement.

Comment: The text always updates, the buttons don't disappear.

Comment: try the View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 btnSignIn.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
```

to

```
btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```